# Creating an 10 names via array from textbox on form 1 and then will show all names on form 2 via list box

Tags: c#

5. Create an application with two forms.  The first form must have two buttons.  The first when clicked must accept a single name and store it in an array of up to 10 names.  The second when clicked must open a separate form holding list box that has the names entered on the first form displayed in it.  Do this in two ways
   (a) Transfer the names to the list box within the first form before displaying the second form
   (b) Transfer the names to the second form by making the array public static and place a button on the second form that when clicked will transfer the names from the array to the  the list box

   enter code here
   FORM1:

   ```
    public partial class frm_main : Form
   {
   public static string[] str_name = new string[10];
   frm_display frm = new frm_display();
   int s;
   public frm_main()

   {

       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void btn_store_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


       for (s = 0; s < str_name.Length; s++)
       {

           str_name[s] = txtBox_name.Text;
           frm.str_name[s] = str_name[s];


       }
       txtBox_name.Clear();
       txtBox_name.Focus();

   }

   private void btn_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


       frm.ShowDialog();

   }
   ```

   }

FORM 2:
         public partial class frm_display : Form
            {

```
    public string[] str_name= new string[10];

    public frm_display()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void btn_showNames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        for (int s=0; s <str_name.Length;s++)
        {

                lstBox_names.Items.Add(str_name[s]);



        }


    }
```

it just show the last name placed in the textbox

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are return; in loop so loop has stopped there. Please remove it.

Instead of storing it to static members, you can directly pass array through parameter.

In form 2

```
public frm_display(Array ary) // Here you will get array you passed from form1
{

}
```

In form 1

```
private void btn_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   form2 frm= new form2(YourArrayHere);
   frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: i removed the return; but it only one name appears.

Comment: Please remove for loop from btn_store_Click and store a TextBox values in array at once. Items will be store on click with changed values in TextBox on each Button click. Then same values you will receive on another form.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of array suggest to use List
Form1

public static List str_name = new List();

```
private void btn_store_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   str_name.Add(txtBox_name.Text);
}
```

Form2

```
foreach(string str in str_name )
{
//here you will get each string in str variable
}
```

Comment: Please correct above line public static List<String> str_name = new List<String> ();

Comment: str_name.Add = txtBox_name.Text has errors. Add cannot be used

Comment: because this answer is not c#

Comment: Please use List as Add is method of List not array

Comment: it should be str_name.Add(txtBox_name.Text)